# Sony Bravia KDL-32L5000 PC resolution slightly off

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a PC running two Nvidia 8500 GTs in SLI mode and I am trying to use my TV in dual mode. When I switch the TV to PC the screen is nearly centered with a slight offset. All resolutions are effected from 800x600 all the way up to the TVs native 1360x768.

I have tried with SLI on and off and have PhysX turned off as well as I thought that might have an effect.

I am running

- Windows XP 64-bit SP2
- DirectX ver 9.0c
- Nvidia driver version 181.22

Answer (score 1):

if the TV is not correctly recognized, disable the option **Hide modes that this monitor cannot display** in the advanced display settings (monitor) ... or use **[Powerstrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**:

> PowerStrip provides advanced,
>   multi-monitor, programmable hardware
>   support to a wide range of graphics
>   cards - from the venerable Matrox
>   Millennium I to the latest ATI Radeon
>   HD series. It is the only program of
>   its type to support multiple graphics
>   cards from multiple chipset vendors,
>   simultaneously, under every Windows
>   operating system from Windows 95 to
>   the x64-bit edition of Vista. A simple
>   menu that pops up from the system tray
>   provides access to some 500 controls
>   over your display hardware, including
>   sophisticated color correction tools,
>   period level adjustments over screen
>   geometry, and driver independent clock
>   controls. A powerful application
>   profiler can detect when programs are
>   launched and respond by activating
>   specific display settings, gamma
>   adjustments, performance switches and
>   even clock speeds - returning
>   everything to normal when the program
>   closes. In-game gamma hotkeys let you
>   light up the darkest hallways during
>   game play, and hardware control over
>   refresh rates - with floating point
>   precision - ensure you're never stuck
>   at just 60Hz no matter what OS you're
>   using. A quick setup wizard gets you
>   up and running with minimal fuss,
>   extensive context-sensitive help is
>   available for all controls, and live
>   updates are supported to ensure you're
>   always running the latest release.
>   Finally, an assortment of system and
>   productivity tools - among them,
>   extensive diagnostics, PCIe and AGP
>   device configuration, EDID decoding,
>   desktop icon management, a system idle
>   thread, Windows resource monitoring,
>   an anti-burn-in orbiting option,
>   physical memory optimization, an
>   on-screen display, and the most
>   advanced monitor support in the
>   industry - round out the compact 1MB
>   package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have haven't figured this out yet what you need to do is go into the TV's menu and go down to the screen settings on the left hand menu and then PC SETTINGS in larger right side menu, make sure you select wide mode normal, and and then use the auto adjustment feature. I had the same problem with my xfx gts core edition 250's in tri-sli mode, and this was the cure.

P.S. You are using the VGA cable I am assuming?  Because if you are using the hd component cables then you need to use the resize desktop in the nvidia control panel and you have to to do this evertime you turn off the tv.